# What to do with the high dv/dt on bridge H?

Tags: power-electronics, noise

I have an H bridge, with a 540V DC link. There is a high level of noise induction across the board (even though all circuits and sources are isolated). Bridge H has drives that provide dual power (+15V/-8V). Tried to verify the implementation of an active Miller Clamp with PNP transistor. Does anyone have any tips or compatible circuit to attenuate the high DV/DT switching?

Comment: RC snubbers. Gate resistors. Tight loops. Proper planes without bridging.

Comment: it's a relatively common subject on the [EE stack](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), check there . . .